# Show divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code http://jsfiddle.net/cwahL1tz/

My HTML

```
<ul class="myFilters">
   <li data-type="A"><a href="#">A</a></li>
   <li data-type="B"><a href="#">B</a></li>
   <li data-type="C"><a href="#">C</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="filter">

<ul class="title">
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="#Assurance">Assurance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="#Couverture">Couverture</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="#Banque">Banque</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="#Alimentation">Alimentation</a></li>
</ul>

    <div id="Assurance" class="category">
    <ul>                                         
        <li>Groupama</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="Couverture" class="category">
    <ul>                                         
        <li>Try it !</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="Alimentation" class="category">
    <ul>                                         
        <li>AN example</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's my JS script

```
jQuery(function ($) {

$('.myFilters li').click(function(){
    $(".category").hide();
       var v = $(this).text()[0]
       $('.title li').hide().filter(function(){
          return $(this).text().toUpperCase()[0] == v;
          $(".category:first").show();
       }).show()
    })



$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
  var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
  $(".category").hide();
  $(selector).show();
});

 });
```

It works fine but I trying to arrange some stuff but I'm stuck.

When I load the page all the links and divs appears, I just only want the divs of the first letter appear.

And when I click on C for example, I want the first div to show from the first link.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: can you make your goal a bit clearer and please add the relevant code to your question and describe what is not working exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

On load:

```
$('.myFilters li:first').trigger('click');
```

And inside its click:

```
.first().find('a[data-toggle]:first').trigger('click');
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/cwahL1tz/15/)

Comment: It's almost that but I want all the links from  the letter. Not only the first div from letter A

Comment: So for example on load you want to see both Assurance and Alimentation? and the contents of both should be visible or just the first in that case?

Comment: Just the first in that case would be perfect

Comment: It displays great but When I click on others letters, the first div of the first link is not appearing like at the beginning.

Comment: B & C each have only one and `Banque` doesn't have any corresponding content. You mean if you click C then Couverture is shown + it's content? Your original question explicitly said otherwise.

Comment: Yes when you click on C then the "Couverture" is shown + it's content

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that with first selecting the element with the [right selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and then you can trigger the click event manually :

1. Show the Assurance content on load :

   ```
   $('a[data-toggle="#Assurance"]').click();
   ```
2. Show first content on click :

   ```
   $('.myFilters li').click(function(){
       $(".category").hide();
       var v = $(this).text()[0]
       $('.title li').hide().filter(function(){
           return $(this).text().toUpperCase()[0] == v;
       }).show()
       $('a[data-toggle]:visible:first').click();
   })
   ```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwahL1tz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Without going into any more javascript, you can display the content the way you would like using css selectors:

```
.category {display:none;}

.category:nth-of-type(1) {
     display:block;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ageasm4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want. Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwahL1tz/7/)

I am basically just triggering the first item in the `li`

```
$(".title > li:first").find("a[data-toggle]").trigger("click");
```

and i am doing the same with the category.

***EDIT***

I updated my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/072m8w31/1/)

***NEW EDIT***

Created a new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf8Lf1hb/1/), this one just removes all the duplicate code.
So basically i created these 2 functions

```
    that.selectFirstElem = function(selector){
        selector.find("a[data-toggle]").trigger("click");
    };

    that.loadFirstDataToggle = function(input){
        return $('.title li').hide().filter(function(){
              return $(this).text().toUpperCase()[0] == input;
          }).show();
    };
```

And those 2 functions you can just call in the places where you need it.

Comment: It works ! But what I need to is when you load the page, display all the links from the first letter (A)

Comment: ah, i understand, i am updating the fiddle

Comment: I added a new fiddle for you. Let me know if it works for you